# Which non-bank-specific online money management applications work for Canadian banks?

Tags: canada, online-applications, websites, online-banking

[Mint.com](http://mint.com) has languished for years ([over three now](http://forums.mint.com/archive/index.php/t-593.html)) in not supporting Canadian banks. Given that we only have a few, you would think it to be a small amount of work.

**Update: Mint.com now supports Canadian banks! You just need to enter a zip code to create your account.**

Which online banking sites (apart from your own bank's) have people used for Canadian accounts?

Comment: Similar: http://www.basicallymoney.com/questions/1059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Mint.com actually uses [Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com/) for the back end, which does support Canadian banks. However, I've found their UI to be only OK at best. The actual website is called [Yodlee MoneyCenter](http://www.yodlee.com/ymc%5Fhome.shtml).

I've recently discovered that [Thrive](http://justthrive.com) supports all the Canadian financial institutions; you can enter any zip code to create your account.

It would still be nice if Mint started supporting Canadians...

Comment: That Thrive link is missing the .com on the end.

Comment: looks like Thrive is dead