# What's a good personal finance management web app that I can use in Canada?

Tags: online-applications, canada

I'm looking for an intuitive free to use personal finance management web application. There's a whole bunch of them out there and the few that seems modern are:

```
www.buxfer.com
www.wesabe.com
www.budgetpulse.com
money.strands.com
www.moneytrackin.com
www.justthrive.com
```

I plan to try each one of them but that might take me a while to find my perfect match. Which personal finance web app do you guys use or recommend?

**EDIT**

I've already checked out Mint, it's for US users only.  I'm looking for a web app for Canadian or International users.

Comment: .... if it's Canada-specific, mentioning Canada helps. I've gone and tagged it as such.

Comment: If you are with CIBC, or PC Financial, you're going to be out of luck in trying to automatically connect to your account.  They are actively blocking financial aggregators.

Answer (score 9):

Now, if you're still intrested, Mint.com works also for Canadian banks.

**[Mint Canada](https://www.mint.com/canada/)**

Answer (score 4):

Yodlee will also work. I asked a similar question (and provided answers) [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/947/which-non-bank-specific-online-money-management-applications-work-for-canadian-ba).

Thrive, so far, is the best in my opinion. Their tech support is top notch and their UI is far superior to Yodlee's (which provides the backend for Mint).

Comment: Thrive seems to be dead

Answer (score 3):

I use MoneyStrands (formerly called Expensr), but mostly just to track expenses and look at reports on my spending habits. It has some really pretty charts, with the ability to drill down into categories and sub-categories, or graph monthly spending for any custom date range. It does a half-decent job of auto-categorizing the imported bank transactions, and you can set up additional rules for common vendors, but I still have to do some manual work after each import. It does a good job of integrating my credit cards, bank accounts, and I can even manually add cash transactions. It has some basic budgeting capabilities, but they're not very useful for someone who needs to carefully budget thier monthly spending.

Another one I've heard about is mint.com, but it only supports American banks (last I heard, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link with comparison of various online and offline PF software: http://personalfinancesoftwarereviews.com/compare-personal-finance-software/

Answer (score 1):

Now, keep in mind I'm biased because I'm an engineer at this company, but [FutureAdvisor.com](http://www.futureadvisor.com) provides advice on your savings and investments.  We currently help users optimize their portfolios for retirement savings, but plan on rolling our more savings goals in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[CashBase](http://www.cashbasehq.com) has a web app, an iPhone app and an Android app, all sync'ed up. It doesn't integrate with banks automatically, but you can import bank statements as CSV.

*Disclosure: Filip is CashBase's founder.*